# What is the definition of an sh Lie derivative or $L_\infty$ derivative?

Tags: homotopy-theory, lie-derivative, dg-lie-algebras

How is the traditional Cartan definition of Lie derivative generalized to sh Lie or $L_\infty$? and where?